# What is the Klingon Bloodwine made of?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, klingon

Do we know what the Klingon Bloodwine is actually made of? Is it actually as the name suggests? or is it just referring to the colour of it?

Comment: I for one am curious what the actual stuff was on-set.  My guess is Cranberry Juice.

Comment: The blood of grapes?

Comment: Apparently you're not the only person wondering about this: https://twitter.com/RikerGoogling/status/503970853663830016

Comment: See my answer below (direct from the writers).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's never made clear in the on-screen canon, but according to the [Star Trek Cookbook](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2xwzZIdX2hMC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22Klingon%20bloodwine%20is%20exactly%20what%20it%20says%20it%20is:%20fermented%20blood%20and%20sugar%22&source=bl&ots=ZWS3h2030a&sig=4MlFXU_b4N7xGdD14c9m1dyLi4k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C7IBVIrXNYGy7Ab5uYHQBQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Klingon%20bloodwine%20is%20exactly%20what%20it%20says%20it%20is%3A%20fermented%20blood%20and%20sugar%22&f=false) (by Ethan Phillips and William J. Birnes):

> "Klingon bloodwine is exactly what it says it is: fermented blood and
>   sugar."

There's been a lot of speculation among fans as to how one is supposed to interpret Worf's quote:

> "I like my bloodwine **very young, and very sweet**."

Comment: Young wine means low amounts of fermentation - low alcohol. Yeast eats sugars, the more sugar, the more alcohol. So his blood wine preference is not overly weak, but isn't terribly strong, either.

Comment: Aye, that's why people like speculating about whether he was talking age/sweetness in typical wine terms, or if it's something more sinister/Klingon ;)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the blood can and does ferment. [Here](http://www.duiblog.com/2005/04/14/fermentation-in-blood-samples-produce-alcohol/) a lawyer mentions DUI blood sample contamination by fermentation.

Comment: @aramis - depends. If it's truly like wine, then yes, otherwise, aging means that the alcohol is just evaporating, like with scotch (older scotch generally has a lower proof than younger). It all depends on whether the fermentation continues while it ages.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens there are a number of things that change during the maturation process for whisky besides the alcohol evaporating.  The color in the whisky comes from the cask, being slowly dissolved into the whisky.  Some of the other alcohols oxidize or leech into the wood of the cask.  Alcohol and water both evaporate - how much of each depends on temperature and ambient humidity.  Other chemistry occurs to the distillate. I think it's interesting - read here: http://www.shakestir.com/features/id/551/science-of-barrel-aging

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens so, initial cask strength varies depending on regulation and distiller, final cask strength varies, and bottling proof also varies, but is usually at least 40%, regardless of age.

Comment: @pcurry - yeah, I was just reading this one, too: http://www.economist.com/node/457125. Fun stuff. Basically, Worf is either saying he likes young bloodwine because it's weak (like young wine), or strong (because it's cask strength). No way to know, really, and I'm sure the writers didn't think it this far through.

Comment: Wouldn't actual blood coagulate before it could finish fermenting?

Comment: @Nu'Daq It all depends, they could possibly treat it with a natural anti-coagulant. On earth Tumeric, Ginger, Cinnamon, and Cayenne contian blood thinners (though concentration/effectiveness is another matter), so who knows what kind of crazy herbs or venoms grow on Quo'Nos which could be added to the brew. They may also have some way of filtering out platelets or proteins which would otherwise cause coagulation.

Answer (score 18):

## Blood of their enemies and sugar

*TNG* writer Ronald D. Moore (responsible for much of the Klingon arc in *TNG*) was asked this question today at the **Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration** in Las Vegas.

> **MOORE:** The blood of their enemies.  And it would be really, really sweet.  They like it sweet.  So blood with a lot of sugar.

Comment: So, exactly what the ST: Cookbook says it is. Nice confirmation.

Comment: @Valorum : Thanks.  He was a little more specific, of course: the blood of their *enemies*, not just any old blood that you get on offer from Tesco.

Comment: By "their enemies", I took it to mean simply any race considered to be an enemy of the Klingon Empire rather than the specific enemies of the House of Mogh/Duras, etc.

Comment: @Valorum : That's also what I took it to mean --- enemies in general.  But I'm differentiating between blood of enemies killed in glorious battle and the blood of a [targ](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/f/fe/Targ.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120729150638&path-prefix=en) that died of old age at its master's feet, i.e. not *any* blood will do.

Comment: Fair enough. I think you deserve the acceptance, simply for the quality of the source.

Comment: @Valorum : Thanks --- I don't mind either way, personally.

Answer (score 3):

In *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* Martok boasts that he has a barrel of 2309 bloodwine and that there is no finer "vintage".  "Vintage" when used to refer to wine implies grapes or at least something that grows in a vineyard.  So I don't think bloodwine contains blood any more than [*sangria*](http://wine.about.com/od/howwineismade/a/sangriaessentia.htm) contains [*sangre*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangre).

Comment: I don't doubt that's where the word comes from, but it appears to have moved on to be used a lot more broadly than that; Dictionary.com gives "a time of origin" as one definition, and there are vintage ales, vintage whiskeys...

...so I wouldn't be too sure grapes (or the Klingon equivalent of grapes) are at all involved.

Comment: Just as @loghaD suggested, vintage just refers to when something was made, and little else. It doesn't refer to the batch of grapes themselves, nor the hops or any other kinds of ingredients, just the year it was made.

Comment: Given that the federation/Klingon war didn't fully end until 2344, one has to wonder what enemies blood was used to make that vintage of wine.

Comment: A vintage car doesn't grow on a vineyard. neither does a vintage 1950s comic book. Thats maybe where the word originally came from, but it has long encompassed a much broader meaning.